# mysql inner join causing multiplication

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, inner-join

basically i have this structure:

- Deal has and belongs to many Channels
- Deal has many DealSales
- Deal belongs to Channel

When i want to find the amount sold by a deal, i use this query:

```
SELECT targets.id,SUM(deal_sales.amount_sold) AS amount_sold
FROM deal_sales 
INNER JOIN deals ON deals.id = deal_sales.deal_id 
INNER JOIN targets ON deals.target_id = targets.id 
WHERE targets.approved = 1 AND targets.active = 1
GROUP BY targets.id
```

its working just fine, the problem is when i need to filter by channel, find the amount sold by a deal in a channel:

```
SELECT targets.id,SUM(deal_sales.amount_sold) AS amount_sold
FROM deal_sales 
INNER JOIN deals ON deals.id = deal_sales.deal_id 
INNER JOIN targets ON deals.target_id = targets.id 
**INNER JOIN channels_deals ON channels_deals.deal_id = deals.id**
WHERE targets.approved = 1 AND targets.active = 1
GROUP BY targets.id
```

When i add the join to channels table, the **amount_sold** is multiplied by each channel a deal has relation with. How can i avoid this?

Comment: are rules number 1 and 3 correct?, Deal 'has and belongs to many' or 'belongs to' Channel(s)???

Comment: and what about targets?, a deal belongs to a target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IN or Exists

for example

```
SELECT targets.id,SUM(deal_sales.amount_sold) AS amount_sold
FROM deal_sales 
INNER JOIN deals ON deals.id = deal_sales.deal_id 
INNER JOIN targets ON deals.target_id = targets.id 

WHERE targets.approved = 1 AND targets.active = 1
  and 
   deals.id IN (SELECT deal_id from channels_deals where something = 1)
GROUP BY targets.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

SELECT channels_deals.deal_id,SUM(deal_sales.amount_sold) AS amount_sold
FROM deal_sales 
INNER JOIN deals ON deals.id = deal_sales.deal_id 
INNER JOIN targets ON deals.target_id = targets.id 
INNER JOIN channels_deals ON channels_deals.deal_id = deals.id
WHERE targets.approved = 1 AND targets.active = 1
GROUP BY channels_deals.deal_id
```